# Let's change text of "resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers" close reason

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons

I occasionally vote to close a question because I believe it was "resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers". Often enough others agree that the question does get closed.

A recent example is a question where a user asked why a feature introduced in version N of Vim wasn't working in a version of Vim later than N, only to realise in the comments that they actually were using a version of Vim *earlier* than N.

So this is all working correctly, except the full text of the close reason is:

> This question was caused by a problem that **can no longer be reproduced** or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

This, more specific, reason often doesn't *technically* apply, but it's still the closest reason from the current list.

I therefore propose changing the text of the close reason.

I'm open to improvements, but as a starting point, how about simply:

> This question was **resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers**.

Or if we wanted to include the existing requirements:

> This question was **resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers**. (It can no longer be reproduced, or was caused by a simple typographical error, etc.)

Comment: Just so I'm clear, your idea is to centralize the main point (that the Q is unlikely to help future readers) and let the subsidiary points be, well, subsidiary? I'm in favor of that.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Precisely.

Answer (score 6):

After the discussion on my previous answer, I'll post this as a separate votable answer (slightly modified from what I suggested in the comments):

> **Unlikely to help future readers**
>
> While similar questions may be [on-topic](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, this question was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers because it can no longer be reproduced, was caused by a simple typographical error, or caused by another issue that is unlikely to be encountered by future readers.

Comment: Given the lack of major changes/activity here since September, I'm going to make the edits for this to become the close reason.

Comment: (…just as soon as I can remember how to do it.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm very happy with Martin's answer, but it never got implemented, so suggesting another version in case it's preferable:

> **Unlikely to help future readers**
>
> Similar questions may be [on-topic](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, but this specific issue is unlikely to be encountered by other users. For example, it may no longer be reproducible, or may have been caused by a simple typographical error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't overly care about the *exact* verbiage, but I feel it's important to keep a reference to "while similar questions may be on-topic here" or something along those lines, which your proposals drop. It communicates there is nothing wrong with this type of question *as such*. Without it, people might think "oh, plugin questions are off-topic" or some such.

---

This current text was, if I remember correctly, copied verbatim from what Stack Overflow had at the time (2015). The current text on Stack Overflow is:

> **Not reproducible or was caused by a typo**
>
> While similar questions may be [on-topic](/help/on-topic) here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers.

This still retains "not reproducible or was caused by a typo" in the title, but I think that's okay as it covers 99% of the questions. The actual text is much shorter though.

So I propose we just copy/update it again from Stack Overflow, which seems like a fine phrasing to me.

Comment: While I don’t fully agree that it’s necessary, I also have no problem adding “while similar questions may be on-topic here” back in. However, your suggestion is  just a more concise version of the current text, so I take it you disagree with my suggestion that the reason should be broadened to encompass things that aren’t typos or “can’t reproduce”?

Comment: I do want to keep the "on-topic" phrase, but I agree with Rich that the focus is in the wrong place with SO's close reason (and that it is too concise).

Comment: @Rich `I take it you disagree with my suggestion that the reason should be broadened to encompass things that aren’t typos or “can’t reproduce”` I'm not opposed to it, but in my experience the overwhelming majority of times the close reason is used it's for a typo or "can't repro", and keeping it in there makes it a bit clearer and concrete, IMHO ("unlikely to help future readers", why?)

Comment: How about `Unlikely to help future readers` as the title with the text `While similar questions may be on-topic here, this question was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers because it can no longer be reproduced, was caused by a simple typographical error, or caused by another issue that is unlikely to be encountered by other people.`?